# What can I do about a phone jack protruding from the wall?

Tags: telephone, phone-wiring

I just moved into a home built in 1962 and so there are still a bunch of land-lines connected. I just removed a telephone from my kitchen that had a phone jack behind it. See the picture below:

[image: Phone Jack Protruding]

What can I do to remove this?

Comment: behind the big flat metal part there's a standard outlet box. you can put a blank plate on it for less obtrusion, or remove it all and patch the drywall. I would try to run 5v to it and put in USB outlets to avoid mud work.

Comment: Yes, get yourself a standard blank plate in your favorite color, remove the telephone plate and there should be a mounting yoke that also needs to be removed and then you can mount the blank plate on the box behind it.

Comment: In the  1960's it was common if not standard policy to install phone outlets with out a box. If you can locate the wire in the basement, disconnect it. Pull the wire out of the wall.  you will likely have a pencil sized hole in the wall.

Comment: That is a special magic plate that is made for wall phones, in case you want to do it Adama style.  (Adama on the 2004 Galactica series was *really* into hardwired lines.)